# How to update OpenSSL version on AWS Lambda?

Tags: openssl, aws-lambda

How can I update the OpenSSL version, currently `OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015` used in a Lambda function?

I need to build the Lambda environment with OpenSSL version 1.10 which supports the multiple `-cert` option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can include `openssl version 1.10` with native libraries with your Lambda. This way you don't need to use the openssl given by the lambda container.

Alternatively you can also create your container with updated openssl and run with Fairgate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It'd be pretty useful if you indicated how though